# SELECTing from MySQL based on Previous Refined MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql

really didn't want to ask this because I'm sure its simple but:

I have a database of users which include fields for postcode(zipcode) and Date of Birth.

A visitor can search for a user by age and distance to their own location. To do this, I have to SELECT all users, then calculate their age, and then calculate their distance, something like this:

```
$result = queryMysql("SELECT user FROM table WHERE user !='$user' ORDER BY joindate DESC ");
$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $num ; ++$j)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
if ($row[0] == $user) continue;

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE user='$row[0]'";
$res=mysql_query($query);
$users=mysql_fetch_assoc($res);

//Get Date of Birth and Calculate Age
$dob = $users['age'];
$age = ...

//Get Profile's Postcode and Calculate Distance 
$profilepc = $views['postcode'];
$distance = ...

if(($distance <200) AND ($age >18 AND <30)) {

}
```

So far, no problem. However I then want to run another query (for pagination) selecting ONLY those users who fit within the age and distance parameters set by the visitor, which i can echo in the above IF statement, but i don't know how to include in a new Query.

So, HOW do I place the results of the first query into something(an array?), and then user the user_id's (which are unique) from that first query to only select the required users for my pagination? Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE user_id=(filtered user_id's) ORDER BY joindate DESC
```

I hope that makes sense.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery for your `IN` clause, or if you already have a PHP array of IDs:

```
// assuming your array of IDs is
$user_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4);

// use implode() to create a comma separated list for use in your IN clause
$query = "SELECT * FROM {$table}
WHERE user_id IN (" . implode(',', $user_ids) . ") 
ORDER BY joindate DESC;"
```

Comment: thanks, my array of user_id's echos out like this: Array ( [0] => 68 ) Array ( [0] => 69 ) Array ( [0] => 70 ) etc etc, should that work with your implode query? Thanks

Comment: You don't want to `var_dump` the array, you want to make a string. try `echo implode(',', $user_ids);` and you'll see the string that goes into the `IN ()`

Comment: It doesn't separate the ID's with a comma. I haven't used arrays before so this is all new to me. How should I get my selected user_ids into an array properly?

Comment: `$user_ids[] = $user_id;` where `$user_id` is each id from your first query (assuming you are looping through the results).

Comment: Thanks doublesharp, repped. I'm getting some weird duplication going on for user_ids though.

Comment: That is because your initial query is returning duplicates. For your `IN` clause it won't matter, but I suspect it will affect other things. You can remove them from your array with `array_unique()` but you probably want to sort out the initial query. Distances can be tricky.

Answer (score 5):

Use `IN` instead of `=`

```
SELECT * FROM $table
WHERE user_id IN (select user_id from other_table where some_condition) 
ORDER BY joindate DESC
```

Comment: thanks Juergen but what is it that i put in (filtered user_ids)? I don't know how to store that? Or i do but i don't realise it.

Comment: Specifically, if you have an `array` of `user_ids` like `$user_ids = array(1, 2, 3, 4)` you can use `implode(',', $user_ids)`.

Comment: You can do a single query if you get the ids from another select like in my updated answer

Comment: I've added how I get to my users with the correct Age & distance to my original question (the IF statement), but I don't know(understand) how to then use that to get the relevant user_id's for a new query

Comment: I am not familiar with PHP. But looking at your code it is very slow to query the users and then select data from the DB for every user again. Not knowing how you calculate age and distance I guess you can do that in one single query.

Comment: I think your query should be something like `SELECT user FROM table WHERE user <> '$user' and calculaed_age between 19 and 29 and calculated_distance < 200 ORDER BY joindate DESC`

Comment: The trouble is I need to get the date of birth and postcode out of the database before I can calculate their age and distance.

Comment: you can calculate the date and distance probably on the fly. See [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for instance `datediff`

Answer (score 1):

If you can do something with SQL it's most time the best and fastest option. The query bellow will select all users except for one where the age (in years) is more then 30 years.

I could not write the SQL for the distance because I don't know your data and thus don't know how to calculate it. However I added some place where it can be added.

The "limit" clause will fetch the records from 10 to 20 in the database.

```
   SELECT 
       * 
    FROM 
       table
    WHERE 
       user != $user
       and (
           (year(now()) - year(table.birthday))  > 30
           or (some match to calculate distance)
        )
    limit 10, 20
```

If you need more data from another table you can join them together like this.

```
   SELECT 
       * 
    FROM 
       table
       another_table
    WHERE 
       another_table.user = table.user
       table.user != $user
       and (
           (year(now()) - year(table.birthday))  > 30
           or (some match to calculate distance)
        )
    limit 10, 20
```

Making several select and looping data in any language is slow compared to selecting in a database.